# glossaries and csquotes: how to use autoquotes in gls description?

Tags: glossaries, csquotes, active-characters

I am trying to get `csquotes`'s `\MakeAutoQuote` to work with `glossaries` - no luck so far. The defined autoquotes are simply not active anymore by the time the description is read.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[german]{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[autostyle,english=american,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{“}{”}

\usepackage[xindy,nonumberlist,numberedsection=nolabel]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{Test}{
    name={Test},
    text={Test},
    description={Here “it doesn't” work.}}  % <--- quotes not active!

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
    “works”

    \glsaddall
    \printglossary
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

I don't quite understand it. The string is not written to any file, the quote characters are non-standard (so they are unlikely to be overwritten), and they are made active before the `\newglossaryentry` macro. Any ideas?

PS: to compile the MWE, save it as `glossary.tex`, then:

```
lualatex glossary.tex 
makeglossaries glossary
lualatex glossary.tex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, reading the `csquotes` source (and then I also found it in the docs, duh!) helps. Active quotes are only enabled `\AtBeginDocument`. So both of those solutions work if used in the preamble:

```
\@enablequotes
\newglossaryentry{Test}{...}
```

or

```
\AtBeginDocument{\newglossaryentry{Test}{...}}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use  `\newglossaryentry` in `\AtBeginDocument` or it will trigger the creation of the `.glsdefs` file (unless you use `\usepackage[docdef=restricted]{glossaries-extra}`).

Comment: Indeed, I wondered about that message since it sits there for a while :) I solved it with your hint from the manual: put the `\AtBeginDocument` line before the `\usepackage{glossaries}` and then it won't create the file either. Thank you!